# To find dimension of null space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

For $n\in{N}$ let $P_{n}$ denote the vector space of all polynomials with real coeffecients of degree at most $n$. Define $$ T: P_{n}\rightarrow P_{n-1} $$ by 
 $$T(p)(x) = p'(x)-\int_{0}^{x} {p(t)dt} $$ 
Then how to find dimension of the null space of $T$?

Comment: You must have thought deeply of the problem, please share with us..

Comment: How to find its transformation matrix p(x)=a+bx^{2}+....+g_{i}x^{n} and now will I have to find its transformation ? If I got its transformation then how I will get its matrix form as coffecient includes a, b-a,...

Comment: There appears to be a typo. Your transformation's codomain should be $P_{n+1},$ instead.

Answer (score 3):

You want to know when is it true that $p'(x)=\int_0^xp(t)\,\mathrm dt$. If the degree of $p(x)$ is $k\in\mathbb N$, then the degree of $p'(x)$ is $k-1$ and the degree of $\int_0^xp(t)\,\mathrm dt$ is $k+1$. So, they can't be equal. If $p(x)$ is constant and not $0$, almost the same thing is true; in this case, the degree of $p'(x)$ is $0$ and the degree of $\int_0^xp(t)\,\mathrm dt$ is $1$. So, the null space of your map is $\{0\}$.

Comment: +1: One slight quibble. If $p(x)$ is constant and non-zero, then $p'(x)$ is $0$, but the degree of $p'(x)$ is arguably undefined, or $-\infty.$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: if
$$T(p(x))=p'(x)-\int_0^x p(t) \mathrm d t=0$$
differentiating on both sides you obtain
$$p''(x)=p(x)-p(0)$$
What can you conclude if $p$ satisfies this differential equation?

Comment: Well, one can conclude that $p(x)=c\sinh(x)+\left(2e^{-x}-1\right)p(0),$ for some constant $c,$ so isn't a polynomial, at all, unless $c=0$ and $p=0.$ Still, unless one is familiar with differential equations, that's a long way to go.